# jQuery click unbound after Ajax call that modifies page HTML using html() method of page element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery v3.6.0 on a page that should dynamically allow a user to bookmark/unbookmark an item displayed on the page.

Here is my code snippet:

##### HTML

```
<div id="37.3" class="social-info-container">
   <div id="VK7n" class="social bookmarkable">
    <i title="Bookmarks" class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>0
   </div>
</div>
```

##### Javascript

```
function bookmarkItem(id, elem_id){
  let [ctid, oid] = id.split('.');
    console.log(`Posting bookmark for item with content_type: ${ctid}, object_id: ${oid}`);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
    headers:{'X-CSRFToken': special_csrf_token },
        url: social_bookmark_url,
        data: {
            cid: ctid,
            oid: oid,
      note: ''
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resultData) {
      console.log(`Reponse ok: ${resultData.ok}`);
      console.log(`Elem id: ${elem_id}`);
      $(`div#${elem_id}.social.bookmarkable > i.fa.fa-bookmark`).toggleClass('bookmarked');
      
      let orig_html = $(`div#${elem_id}`).html();
      let old_count = $(`div#${elem_id}`).text();
      let new_count = resultData.count; 
      let new_html = orig_html.replace(old_count,new_count)

      console.log(old_count);
      console.log(orig_html);
      console.log(new_count);

      console.log(new_html);

      $(`div#${elem_id}`).html(new_html);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            if (xhr.status == 403){
        window.location.href = login_url;
      }
      else {
        alert(`Something went wrong: ${xhr.statusText}`);
      }
        }
    });  
}

$().ready(function(){
    $('.social.bookmarkable .fa.fa-bookmark').on('click', function(e) {
      alert('Clicked!');
      let elem_id = $(this).closest('div.social.bookmarkable').attr('id');

      console.log(`Elem id (1): ${elem_id}`);
      let id = $(this).closest('div.social-info-container').attr('id');
      bookmarkItem(id, elem_id);
    });
});
```

When I click the bookmark icon, it works ONCE - after that I have to refresh the page to get it to work again. I thought using the `on()` method to bind to the click event would avoid this problem.

Why is the event being triggered just once - and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the element that the event handler is bound to.  Using `.on()` will only work if the element you bind it to is still around.  You need to also [delegate the handler](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to an element that will always exist, and then use eg [selector context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) to filter for the element you want.

```js
function bookmarkItem(id, elem_id) {
    let [ctid, oid] = id.split('.');
    console.log(`Posting bookmark for item with content_type: ${ctid}, object_id: ${oid}`);
    
    // Fake response to the AJAX call
    let resultData = {
        ok: 'ok',
        count: 1
    };

    $(`div#${elem_id}.social.bookmarkable > i.fa.fa-bookmark`).toggleClass('bookmarked');

    let orig_html = $(`div#${elem_id}`).html();
    let old_count = $(`div#${elem_id}`).text();
    let new_count = resultData.count;
    let new_html = orig_html.replace(old_count,new_count)

    console.log('old_count', old_count);
    console.log('orig_html', orig_html);
    console.log('new_count', new_count);
    console.log('new_html', new_html);

    $(`div#${elem_id}`).html(new_html);
}

$().ready(function(){
    // Attach handler to an element which does not go away, and filter
    // to only match clicks on the element you want. 
    // https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context
    $('.social.bookmarkable').on('click', '.fa.fa-bookmark', function(e) {
        let elem_id = $(this).closest('div.social.bookmarkable').attr('id');
        let id = $(this).closest('div.social-info-container').attr('id');
        
        console.log('Bookmark clicked: elem_id', elem_id, '; id', id);
        
        bookmarkItem(id, elem_id);
    });
});
```

```css
.bookmarked {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="37.3" class="social-info-container">
   <div id="VK7n" class="social bookmarkable">
    <i title="Bookmarks" class="fa fa-bookmark">Click me</i>0
   </div>
</div>
```

There are many examples of this here on SO already, searching for keywords like "*jquery only once*", or "*jquery replace handler once*" turns them up.  I know this well bcs I've done that search in the past :-)  Eg:

- [jQuery - `on` event doesn't work after jQuery.replaceWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149354/jquery-on-event-doesnt-work-after-jquery-replacewith)
- [jquery click only firing once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672021/jquery-click-only-firing-once)
- [JQuery click event works only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194728/jquery-click-event-works-only-once)
- [Jquery .change() event fires only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429645/jquery-change-event-fires-only-once)